# Creating array of options menu using python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create options menu runtime by getting how many options menu they want in runtime.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import *

top = tkinter.Tk()
number_of_pd = Label(top, text="Number of Products")
list2 = ['1','2','3','4','5']
E_Name=['','','','','','']
a=['','','','','','']
def New_number_of_pd(oE_number_of_pd):
 y_axis=300
 num=1
 for num in range(int(oE_number_of_pd)):
    y_axis=y_axis+75
    E_Name[num]= OptionMenu(top,a[num],*list2)
    E_Name[num].place(x=y_axis,y=150)
oE_number_of_pd=StringVar()
E_number_of_pd= OptionMenu(top, oE_number_of_pd, *list2,command=New_number_of_pd)
number_of_pd.place(x=150,y=75)
E_number_of_pd.place(x=300,y=75)
top.title('Sri Sai')
top.geometry('2000x1000') # Size 200, 200
top.mainloop()
```

In number of products text box enter the number of options menu that is required.The buttons are getting created.However I am getting error as below

[image]

Comment: Hello,below code works

Comment: create empty list and use `append()` to add new element to this list - this way you will not have problem with index.

Comment: Hello,I have a diubt.I used append to add in list.I am facing other issues which i posted in below link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47966301/issue-in-accessing-elements-in-array-of-option-menu-created-in-python-tkinter can you please let me know your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You can create empty lists and use `append()` then there is no problem with index.

BTW: because you have numbers as options so you can use list with numbers `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and `IntVar`

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def add_optins_menus(number):
    global all_optins_menus
    global all_vars

    # remove previous options menus
    for widget in all_optins_menus:
        widget.destroy()

    all_optins_menus = []
    all_vars = []

    # add new options menu
    for num in range(number_var.get()):
        var = tk.IntVar()

        widget = tk.OptionMenu(top, var, options)
        widget.pack(side="left")

        all_vars.append(var)
        all_optins_menus.append(widget)

# --- main ---

options = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

all_optins_menus = []
all_vars = []

# ---

top = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(top, text="Number of Products")
label.pack(side="left")

number_var = tk.IntVar()

options_menu = tk.OptionMenu(top, number_var, *options, command=add_optins_menus)
options_menu.pack(side="left")

top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Below code works.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import *

top = tkinter.Tk()
number_of_pd = Label(top, text="Number of Products")
list2 = ['1','2','3','4','5']
E_Name=['','','','','','']
a=['','','','','','']
b=[StringVar(),StringVar(),StringVar(),StringVar(),StringVar()]
def New_number_of_pds(b):
    print(b)
def New_number_of_pd(oE_number_of_pd):
 y_axis=300
 num=1
 for num in range(int(oE_number_of_pd)):
    y_axis=y_axis+75
    E_Name[num]= OptionMenu(top,b[num],*list2,command=New_number_of_pds)
    E_Name[num].place(x=y_axis,y=150)
oE_number_of_pd=StringVar()
E_number_of_pd= OptionMenu(top, oE_number_of_pd, *list2,command=New_number_of_pd)
number_of_pd.place(x=150,y=75)
E_number_of_pd.place(x=300,y=75)
top.title('Sri Sai')
top.geometry('2000x1000') # Size 200, 200
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should explain the modifications a bit for it to be good answer.