# Issue in accessing elements in array of option menu created in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I created options menu in run time based on user inputs.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import *

top = tkinter.Tk()
number_of_pd = Label(top, text="Number of Products")
list2 = ['1','2','3','4','5']
E_Name=['','','','','','']
a=[]
b=[StringVar(),StringVar(),StringVar(),StringVar(),StringVar()]
def New_number_of_pds(b):
    a.append(b)
    print(a)
    print(b)
def New_number_of_pd(oE_number_of_pd):
 y_axis=300
 num=1
 for num in range(int(oE_number_of_pd)):
    y_axis=y_axis+75
    E_Name[num]= OptionMenu(top,b[num],*list2,command=New_number_of_pds)
    E_Name[num].place(x=y_axis,y=150)
oE_number_of_pd=StringVar()
E_number_of_pd= OptionMenu(top, oE_number_of_pd, *list2,command=New_number_of_pd)
number_of_pd.place(x=150,y=75)
E_number_of_pd.place(x=300,y=75)
top.title('Sri Sai')
top.geometry('2000x1000') # Size 200, 200
top.mainloop()
```

here options menu is created on the fly.However when i change the options menu the new value is appended not updated since i dont know how to find which option menu is clicked.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`OptionMenu` executes function with one agument - selected value - so you have to use `lambda` with two arguments

```
command=lambda val, n=num:new_number_of_pds(val, n))
```

First is selected value, second will be optionmenu's number "num".

And then function has to get two arguments

```
def new_number_of_pds(value, optionmenu_number):
```

I don't know what you try to do with those elements but if you want to replace item in list then maybe you should create list with 5 empty elements which you can replace with values.

```
optionmenu number: 0
value: 3
a: ['3', None, None, None, None]
-----
optionmenu number: 2
value: 5
a: ['3', None, '5', None, None]
-----
```

Code

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def new_number_of_pds(value, optionmenu_number):
    print('optionmenu number:', optionmenu_number)
    print('value:', value)

    a[optionmenu_number] = value
    print('a:', a)
    print('-----')

def new_number_of_pd(oE_number_of_pd):
    global a

    # delete previous values 
    a = [None, None, None, None, None]

    for num in range(int(oE_number_of_pd)):
        E_Name[num] = tk.OptionMenu(top, b[num], *list2, command=lambda val, n=num:new_number_of_pds(val, n))
        E_Name[num].pack(side="left")

# --- main ---

list2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

E_Name=[None, None, None, None, None]

a = [None, None, None, None, None]

top = tk.Tk()
b = [tk.StringVar(), tk.StringVar(), tk.StringVar(), tk.StringVar(), tk.StringVar()]

number_of_pd = tk.Label(top, text="Number of Products")
number_of_pd.pack(side="left")

oE_number_of_pd = tk.StringVar()

E_number_of_pd = tk.OptionMenu(top, oE_number_of_pd, *list2, command=new_number_of_pd)
E_number_of_pd.pack(side="left")

top.mainloop()
```